# JavaFX - Notification when content of TableColumn is cropped?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Does JavaFX provide any listener that fires, if the content of a TableColumn is cropped?

I have a resizable TableColumn and I want to add a tooltip that is displayed only, if the column's content is not fully visible. But right now I cannot determine, whether the text is fully displayed or cropped.

In my table column I'm using a `Label` and set `lblText.setWrapText(true)`.

```
 +------------------+
 |                  |      +--------------------------+
 | This is a very   |<----+| This is a very long text |
 | long tex...      |      +--------------------------+
 |                  |
 +------------------+
 |                  |
 | Short text       |
 |                  |
 +------------------+
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if you really want a listener/an event, as it would only fire upon creation of the long text. I bet that you don't want ALL the long texts in your table popping a tooltip, but maybe the one that you are hovering. Then the event is hovering over the table cell and you want to check "long text" as a property. Here I have no definite answer, but I would assume that the width of the text component is bigger than the width of the column. So couldn't you simply compare these two?

Comment: Use the toolTip, Add the text to the toolTip.

Comment: The text in my column wraps. I cannot compare text length with column width. It would be more useful, if JavaFX could directly tell me, when it's cropping text (and adding dots).

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires private API (which is not adviced).

It uses `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledText`, the actual view of the label, to get notifications on any change.

Once we show the table, we can use lookupAll to find all these nodes, since they use `text` as CSS selector. Then we add a listener for any change in their text (which is the text displayed on the table).

Inside this listener you can add the code you need to display a tooltip.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Label> table = new TableView<>();

    Scene scene = new Scene(table);        
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    table.lookupAll(".text").stream()
            .filter(t->t instanceof LabeledText)
            .map(t->(LabeledText)t)
            .forEach(t->{
                t.textProperty().addListener((obs, s0, s1) -> {
                    System.out.println(((Label)t.getParent()).getText()+" -> "+s1);
                });
            });
}
```